# Calculating a net result and storing this against a row for a specific item

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I hope some one can assist. I need to generate a view that contains a running balance of Quantity for an Item. The system that we are using has no concept of allocating or reserving stock

I will have attempt this with in SQL. There for the procedure must be run when the view is called.

The view will consist of 2 tables,

## Qty In Stock Table

Code  A

Warehouse North

QtyInStock 10

## Requirement Table

JOBNR 123

Code  A

Warehouse to Draw From  North

Qty Required    5

JOB 123 is the first job to use code A, there for the calculation is easy

QtyInStock - Qty Required

10 - 5  = 5

As soon as another job comes in then the next job must use the previous lines result to recalculate the  net result.

JOBNR 456

Code  A

Warehouse to Draw From  North

Qty Required    3

There for

Previous Reult - Requirement 
5 - 3 = 2

Sorry for maybe explaining this poorly. I hope some one can assist.

The Server is SQL 2008 but Management studio that I use is SQL 2012

Comment: I see this post that might lead into right direction: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.